# Cypress test is timing out

Tags: cypress

I need to validate that one of the elements I am searching for appears on the page.

if one of them appears the expect statement should evaluate to true.

I have pressed f12 and validated that the 'downloadReferencesRow' along with one of the other elements is appearing. but cypress it timing out.

Does my code look ok?

```
var numberOfElements = 0;


cy.get('downloadReferencesRow').then((body) =>{
    if (body.find('createApplicationReferencesPresent').length > 0) {
        numberOfElements +=1;
    }
    if (body.find('createApplicationNoReferencesPresent').length > 0) {
        numberOfElements +=1;
    }
});

expect(numberOfElements).eq(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code has mixed synchronous and asynchronous commands, which is problematic.

You can more easily do it with jQuery multiple selectors

```js
cy.get('createApplicationReferencesPresent,createApplicationNoReferencesPresent')
  .then($els => {
    const numberOfElements = $els.length  // 1 or 2 - fails if neither present
  })
```

Like all conditional testing, it only works if the page is stable.